# C++ Variable number of std::vector arguments results in exception: std::bad_array_new_length

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I'm trying to pass a variable number of std::vector to a function, but I get the below exception.
I'm using Visual Studio 16 2019

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <type_traits>
#include<tuple>

class Test
{
public:

    template <class ...Trgs>
    void funct(...)
    {
        int n = 2;
        va_list vr;
        va_start(vr, n);

        if (std::is_same<std::tuple_element<1, std::tuple<Trgs...> >::type, std::vector<int> >::value)
            std::cout << "true" << std::endl;

        using ResultType = typename std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<Trgs...> >::type;

        ResultType x = va_arg(vr, ResultType);

        using ResultType2 = typename std::tuple_element<1, std::tuple<Trgs...> >::type;

        ResultType2 y = va_arg(vr, ResultType2);

        va_end(vr);
    }
};


int main()
{
    Test t;
    std::vector<bool> c = { 0 };
    std::vector<int> d = { 1 };
    t.funct<std::vector<bool>, std::vector<int> >(c, d);

    for (int i = 0; i < c.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << c[i] << std::endl;
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x76B74662 in TestT.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_array_new_length at memory location
```

at this line:

```
ResultType x = va_arg(vr, ResultType);
```

Is this related to the fact that some compilers have issues with variable number of arguments when the arguments are structures/classes?

Answer (score 4):

C-ellipsis is different than variadic template.
C-ellipsis accepts just a [limited kind of type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments#Default_conversions) (`std::vector` is not part of those).

You don't need C-ellipsis here:

```
template <class ...Ts>
void funct(const Ts&... args)
{
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Jarod42 already stated, you missed to really refer to newer C++ variadic templates and mixed things up a bit here. You're not the first one with that issue, it's quite likely to happen.

For the actual reason why you crashed (be happy with that, several online compilers run fine here though it is undefined behavior actually... MS VS2017 emits warnings at least), see here for instance:

https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-4-c4840?view=msvc-160&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2017